# Magento 2 | Route has layout

Tags: magento2, layout, routing

I created a custom route which is working fine.
However it is just a blank page.

How can I add the header and the footer?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain in detail and also check magento mode, be sure it is developer

Comment: As I said I created a custom route. When I call it it is just a blank page. So I want to add the header and footer like on other sites.

Comment: check magento mode, be sure it is developer mode. use this comand to check mode  php bin/magento deploy:mode:show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we will create a helloworld_index_index.xml file in the app/code///view/frontend/layout folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="<vendor>\<Module>\Block\Index" name="helloworld.index" template="helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

create the Index.php controller file in the app/code///Controller/Index folder with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<Module>\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Create a Index.php file in the app/code///Block folder with the following code:

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getHelloWorldTxt()
    {
        return 'Hello world!';
    }
}
```

Create a helloworld.phtml file in the app/code//view/frontend/templates folder with the following code:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->getHelloWorldTxt(); ?></h1>
```

After that clear cache and check.

Comment: can you tell me the layout files name for this route? <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="newsletter_anmeldung" frontName="newsletter_anmeldung">
            <module name="UO_NewsletterUV" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>

Comment: Please create layout file like < newsletter_anmeldung_index_index.xml> in your layout folder